# std::copy is slower for a specific range but same as memcpy without a range

Tags: c++, copy, std, memcpy

I am aware of that different compilers will give me different results. I am using gcc. I know that std::copy actually uses memcpy so the runtime of std::copy and memcpy should be similar.
However, it is not similar when I use a back_inserter() in the std::copy and it is far worse when I use a range in std::copy.

I got the following output with the default optimization flag:

```
vector total push_back time: 28
total copy time using push_back: 18
std::copy with begin() time: 1
std::copy with back_inserter time: 13
memcpy time: 1
std::copy with begin() but with a range: 75
```

However, the executation time changes when I turn on O3 flag but for a range copy, std::copy is still slow.

```
vector total push_back time: 11
total copy time using push_back: 3
std::copy with begin() time: 0
std::copy with back_inserter time: 1
memcpy time: 1
std::copy with begin() but with limits: 64
```

Here is my benchmark code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                   
std::vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < INT8_MAX; i++)
    v.push_back(i);

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                   
int t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count();
cout<<"\n vector total push_back time: "<<t;

s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  
std::vector<int> v2;
for(int i = 0; i < INT8_MAX; i++){
    v2.push_back(v[i]);
}
e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                  
t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count();
cout<<"\n total copy time using push_back: "<<t;


s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::vector<int> v3;
v3.reserve(v.size());
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), v3.begin());
e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                  
t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count();
cout<<"\n std::copy with begin() time: "<<t;




s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::vector<int> v5;
v5.reserve(v.size());
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v5));
e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                  
t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count();
cout<<"\n std::copy with back_inserter time: "<<t;


s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
int* vec4 = new int[INT8_MAX];
::memcpy(vec4, v.data(), sizeof(int)*v.size());
e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                  
t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count();
cout<<"\n memcpy time: "<<t;


s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::vector<int> v10;
v10.reserve(v.size());
static int a = 10000;
std::copy(v.begin(), v.begin()+ a, v10.begin());
e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                  
t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(e - s).count();
cout<<"\n std::copy with begin() but with a range: "<<t;

    

}
```

Comment: `v3.reserve(v.size());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), v3.begin());` is UB.  There are no elements in the vector so you are assigning to uninitialized storage.

Comment: Using `std::back_inserter` forces `std::copy()` to call `push_back()` on every individual element one at a time, so it can't be optimized to utilize any kind of mass memory block copying like `memcpy()` can. `std::copy()` is optimized to use `memcpy()` *when possible*, and it is not possible when using `back_inserter()`. Also, you are logging the times it takes the compiler to construct and allocate the `vector` objects, not just the times it takes to copy the elements.

Comment: What build flags are you using? Is this optimized?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I used default optimization. g++ -std=c++11 t2.cpp -O0 -o out

Comment: @sayemsiam When benchmarking it's important to use optimizations. Implementations use abstractions and rely on compiler optimizations to remove them at compile time.

Comment: Consider using [quick bench](http://quick-bench.com/) for these kinds of tests. It's pretty good at avoiding common mistakes people make when writing their own benchmarks. Edit : Because your test doesn't do anything with the data it copies around, it could optimize any of your test cases out completely.